# Retrieve file last modified from file header using CURL

Tags: php, csv, curl, last-modified

I was wondering if it's possible to acquire the 'last modified datetime' for a csv file using CURL.

I'm relying on a CSV file which is updated randomly to keep a database table up-to-date. I only want to update the database table with the CSV file data when the file has been modified after the last table update.

If you know of a link to docs that describe this I would be grateful if you could post them here.

I did some searching but my search engine was inundated with searches related to html headers.

Comment: Use a curl request with `CURLOPT_HEADER` = true and parse out the last modified date if provided by the server.

Comment: Hi Salman A, That looks like a good answer to me. Feel free to turn your comment in to an answer and I will up-vote it.

Comment: @David.LPower you can see my answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do that with following way by using [CURLOPT_HEADER](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php)

```
<?php
$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
// Only header
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
// Do not print anything to output
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

// get last modified date
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FILETIME, true);

$result = curl_exec($curl);
// Get info
$info = curl_getinfo($curl);

echo "Last modified time : " . date ("d-m-Y H:i:s", $info['filetime']) );
?>
```

Comment: Thanks Hüseyin. That is of great help.